# calling tabactivity from intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a activity and a fragment activity . I want to fetch email id stored in my activity to fragment activity . Can anyone of you tell me how to pass data from activity to fragments . I used bundle but it is not working

Comment: Please share the code where you tried using Bundle. That's usually the way to go

Comment: Share some code for others to help you.....

Comment: @TimoSta i have a login activity(Simple Activity) and i want to fetch my data from databse .My login Activity contains E-mail and password , and my Fragment activity (Navigation Drawer) contains edit profile content . I want to get data of the email filled at my login activity. Can u please help me now ?? I'll be thankful to you.......I'm new over here so i dnt knw much about posting codes over here

Comment: ... - *Please share the code where you tried using Bundle. That's usually the way to go*

Comment: @TimoSta i used it in my activity with the intent:-

Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(key, value);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);

and i used in my fragment activity of navigation drawer:-

Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
int myInt = bundle.getInt(key, defaultValue);

Comment: Please edit this into your question and format it correctly. What exactly was the problem with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your activity:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
Fragment frag=new Frag1();
args.putInt("key", value);
frag.setArguments(args);
```

And now in your fragment class, get the bundle as:

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
if(args.containsKey("key"))
{
args.getInt("key");
}
```